# A good parser in c?

Tags: c, parsing, scanf, delimiter

For example, my input is "Tom,18", corresponding to (string) name, (int) age.

In c/c++, what I did is:

```
char name[100] = { 0 };
char age[4] = { 0 }; //define all variables as char before parsing

char string[100] = { 0 };
const char delims[] = ","; //define delimiter
char *s = string; //pointer to string[0]

int txt_len = strcspn(s, delims); //find length between ','
for (int i = 0; i < txt_len; i++) {
    name[i] = *s; //assign to char[]
    s++; //move pointer
}
s++; //move pointer at ','

//do the same for age
txt_len = strcspn(s, delims);
for (int i = 0; i < txt_len; i++) {
    age[i] = *s;
    s++;
}
s++;
int age1 = atoi(age); //convert to int
```

I found this method not that convenient when input categories become more.
Could someone give me some idea on something similar to scanf, where I can simply do:

```
scanf("%s, %i",name,age) //when stdin is delimited by whitespace
```

Thanks!

Comment: "c/c++" is NOT a language. It looks like you're using C idioms, but how is the code compiled?

Comment: Choose one language, not two.  You will get down-voted if you use both on a question like this.

Comment: Why can't you use scanf?

Comment: 1. There is nothing here that in any way resembles a parser. 2. You cannot write a parser using C string functions. 3. You can't even write much of a scanner with them.

Comment: Not sure why this question got closed.  There are lots of ways of doing "parsing" like this.  As you've discovered, ad-hoc solutions are messy.  A good general-purpose solution is to break up a line of text at whitespace or other delimiters, and then operate on the resulting "words"; one standard function for doing the breaking up is `strtok`.  And sometimes `sscanf` (not `scanf`) is perfectly fine -- as in fact it might be here.  Why can't you use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) to break the input into tokens, then process appropriately. The declaration is:

```
char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );
```

So it might look like:

```
char *delim = " ,";
char *name = strtok(input, delim);
int age = atoi(strtok(NULL, delim));
```

Note: the input will be modified, so don't use a const string.

Answer (score 1):

Few people would describe `scanf` as a "good parser" but it sometimes does the trick. If you want to scan a string rather than a stream, use [`sscanf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html).

Comment: Or even a 'parser' :-|

Comment: So stdin the input to a string, replace ',' with ' ' then use sscanf from the string, is that correct?

Comment: @darth:  in your question, you asked how you could do the equivalent of `scanf("%s, %d", name, &age)` from a string, and the answer is `sscanf(s, "%s, %d", name, &age)`. If that's what you want, that's the answer.